# jQueryUI - tabs usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I'm pretty new on programming trying to create web application which can change the content without loading the menu all over again.

Then i decided to use vertical jquery-ui tabs as a navigator. Using this code

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
        <li><center>Market Data</center></li>
        <li><a href="t1.htm">For Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="t2.htm">For Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="t3.htm">For Test 3</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

The question is this "tabs" of jquery-ui using what mechanic for displaying another htm file inside it AJAX, iframe or what?

Is this a good approach?

And can it handle a complex htm file that involve submit the form, receive a data from web service?

Thank you in advance !

Edit: sorry for not mention this earlier but i want to avoid using AJAX if possible.

Comment: are you using server-side language? PHP? JSP? ASP?

Comment: yes, I'm using JSP for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tabs" of jquery-ui. Like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
        />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur
                    nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper
                    ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus.
                    Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing.
                    Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam
                    molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor
                    nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante,
                    ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed
                    fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut
                    tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed
                    ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing
                    adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel
                    metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis.
                    Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod
                    felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam
                    vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue
                    orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu
                    ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales.
                    Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit
                    ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec,
                    luctus a, lacus.</p>
                <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at,
                    magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque.
                    Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede
                    vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor
                    eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo.
                    Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae,
                    pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo.
                    Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit
                    hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think the question is about loading another HTML page,not html divs within same page..

Comment: yes, i want to know abouot loading another HTML file as a content without refresh all the menu over. Sorry if my question is not clearly enough.

Comment: sorry for not mention this earlier but i want to avoid using AJAX if possible. Is iframe is an other option for this?

Comment: @user2612767 than use iframe in div[id="tabs-3"] instead of content

Answer (score 0):

The loading of HTML pages is done using AJAX, It is a good approach, you can have HTML page calling web services too.. you would have no issues with that..

For more information please refer http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax.html
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Comment: sorry for not mention this earlier but i want to avoid using AJAX if possible. Is there another way to doing this without using AJAX?

Comment: May i know why you want to avaoid AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

**[here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)** you can see the example of tabs in this content come by ajax

[jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)  easily customize according to your requirement

**code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Content via Ajax</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
        />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs({
                    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                            ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur
                    nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper
                    ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus.
                    Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing.
                    Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam
                    molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor
                    nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: My friend saying he want me to avoid using AJAX if possible, saying something like it'll make it more difficult for him. Do you have any other suggestion ? or maybe i should use normal navigation with iframe?